# MongoDB - Sort by latest date in child collection

Tags: mongodb

I am currently attempting to sort a collection in MongoDB using the last date of the child element.

It appears I should be using the .aggregate function, but can't seem to sort it out.

The structure of the data is

```
{
  _id: int,
  cellNumber: string
  messages: [
    {
       _id: int,
       body: string,
       date: Date/Time
    }
  ]
}
```

It looks like I should be using the code

```
db.contacts.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: "$_id", lastDate: { $last: "$messages.date" } } },
  { $sort: { lastDate: 1 } }
])
```

But the element with 2 children always returns 2 dates

expected:

```
{ _id: parentId, lastDate: dateOfLastMessage }
```

actual:

```
{ _id: parentId, lastDate: [ dateOfMessage1, dateOfMessage2 ]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give you the result you want (assuming that by 'last', you mean the most recent date):

```
db.contacts.aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$messages'},
  {$sort: {'messages.date': -1}},
  {$group: {_id: "$_id", messages: {$push: '$messages.date'}}},
  {$project: {messages: {$arrayElemAt: ['$messages', 0]}}},
  {$group: {_id: '$_id', lastDate: {$last: '$messages'}}}
])
```

The `$arrayElemAt` operator was only introduced in Mongo version 3.2.